# Setting connection-factory field dynamically in jms outbound adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to set connection-factory field dynamically in jms outbound adapter .

I am thinking of passing connection object in header and  use it with **expression** like the way we can do with the **destination-expression** .

**destination-expression="headers.DestinationQueueName"**

I could not find anything in Spring Integration's online documentation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; that is not possible; see [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) for how to send messages to dynamic servers. It's for ftp, but the same characteristics apply.

Comment: I am not clear why this is not implemented for connection-factory field ?Anyways thanks for the alternative solution! .

Comment: Simply because nobody has requested it, and there are alternatives. If you only have a few brokers (normal), you can simply wire up an outbound adapter for each and put a router in front. You really only need to use the technique from the sample if you have many brokers and you don't want to wire up an adapter for each.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !